What has become of the m-ch-en package?
I have a not so old document (5 years) that had lots of chemical formulas written with the m-ch-en package. It doesn't compile anymore because the m-ch-en.sty file can't be found. CTAN seems not to know it, could someone point me where I could find it for a local installation (I am ok to use another package for new docs, but not retyping my old) or a package that would have the same syntax (I don't believe it exists).
Thanks for your help.

→ https://github.com/LaTeX-Package-Repositories/latex-context-ppchtex for reasons for removing the files from CTAN and in consequence from, e.g., TeX Live. You could try a historic TeX Live 2022 (or previous).

@cabohah do you know why the context code is no longer distributed?

@cfr No. I'm not using ConTeXt.

can you put a small complete document using m-ch-en into your question, I may see how easy it would be to process it using the repo in @Nbur's answer. (I suspect it's missing some files)

@cfr it's context II so like distributing latex 2.09 rather than latex 2e, the context authors asked it be removed from the distributions by default

As written in texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex-context-ppchtex/README.md

m-ch-de.sty m-ch-en.sty m-ch-nl.sty
were wrappers for additional Context MkII pictex chemistry modules.
However as the underlying Context code is no longer distributed, these
files are preserved in this repository for information, but not
distributed to CTAN.
https://github.com/LaTeX-Package-Repositories/latex-context-ppchtex
David Carlisle   LaTeX Project Licence:
https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt


Thanks for your answer. So I understand I would need to install also the corresponding pictex files if I want to use them. Is it still possible  or the current version of ConText would prevent pictex from working ?

Sorry, I've never used ConTeXt…

Oh wow, I'd totally forgotten about that, and thought "why is my name in this answer" until I checked the link.

The ctan packaging script only packages m-pictex.sty and omits the top level language specific wrappers so only latex-context-ppchtex/m-pictex.sty is on ctan. I really can't recall if the others are omitted because they don't work yet or because I forgot them. If someone confirms they work I could add them to ctan so they appeared in texlive and miktex

@AlainBertrand ConTeXt MkII is I think no longer part of the standard distro - this came up on the ConTeXt mailing list recently - you can I believe still get the files and unzip into a suitable place. But that's a separate questions

@AlainBertrand you should or could already have the underlying pictex files, they are a standard part of texlive and miktex, in texlive they are /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pictex/pictex.sty

Hmm yes the m-ch-?? wrappers are not distributed as they'd take a bit more work to set up @AlainBertrand
